# Why did Merlin pay the merchant if he didn't buy anything?

Tags: plot-explanation, cursed-2020

IN S01E01 of *Cursed*, Merlin meets with a merchant that has a bunch of 'peculiar' items. The merchant shows Merlin an infant with three faces, and shortly after, Merlin pays the man with a sack of coins but doesn't actually take anything. Also, when the merchant thanks Merlin for the payment, Merlin rejects his thanks by firmly saying, 'no'.

**Why did Merlin pay the merchant if he didn't actually buy anything, and why did Merlin reject the Merchant's thanks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He purchased the infant with 3 faces. He just didnt take it right then since he wanted to keep it quiet that he was buying from this merchant.
Thats why when the merchant thanks him for the payment he says "No" as if to say i dont know what your talking about i didnt buy anything.

Its quite clear he doesnt want anyone to know what he is doing.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding was, that it was the sign, which was what he was about. Later he was looking up these signs in the book to see what is coming.

It was probably payment for previously agreed job (of bringing this artifact) and for confidentiality as it was indeed something very illegal, to bring and keep around.